# Created a list in R using gmailr, it looks like a table but I can't convert it to a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, gmailr

I have a list that when I print in the console looks like a dataframe. I want to be able to convert this list to a dataframe (with 7 rows and 2 columns) but I am not sure how to. 
When I unlist this object it just starts to get even messier.

```
library('gmailr')
my_messages <- gm_messages(serch ="a",num_results =7)
length(my_messages)
my_messages
glimpse(my_messages)
```

How do I create a 7x2 dataframe that looks exactly like it does in the console from a list that's structured like it is currently?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling

```
t(data.frame(lapply(my_messages$messages, unlist)))
```

The idea is to apply unlist an each row/message, then to convert it to a dataframe and finally to transpose the whole dataframe.
Let me know, if this helps.

Comment: Okay so this ends up giving me a 0 x 0 matrix, due to the fact that my_messages$messages is NULL. Not used to dealing with lists so not sure how to call objects within lists but it seems like my_messages$messages doesn't work.